# Probability of a random game tournament

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:
In a game with four players A,B,C,D multiple rounds of a game are played.
The chance that one of the four wins each round is equal so everyone has a 25% chance of winning each game.

How can I calculate the probability for each person to be the final winner after a specific number of rounds are played.
Also if I know the current score how can I calculate the new probabilities?

For example:
The current score of each individual player is as followed
A: 1
B: 0
C: 3
D: 2
and there are 10 more rounds to play.

Is there any solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the chance of any distribution of the remaining games rather easily.  It is just the number of orders of that distribution divided by $4^{10}$.  The chance that A wins 4, B wins 3, C wins 2 and D wins 1 is $\frac {10!}{4!3!2!1!4^{10}}=\frac {1575}{131072}\approx 0.012$  The leading part is the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).  That leaves the task of listing the various sets of outcomes that lead to C winning, which is still a pain.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That already helps a little but is there any way to compute all those sets that lead to any player winning? Because as you said listing them all is indeed a pain

Comment: Not that I know of.  The eventual winner has to win at least five games and if he only wins five the others have to be 4-4-3, so there are not so many choices.  That is where I would start.  The lack of symmetry makes it much harder.  The other choice is to run a simulation.  Writing a program that takes a current state of the match, throws random numbers, and figures out the eventual winner is not so hard.  It doesn't give exact answers, but you don't have to figure out all the combinations.